# Elastic Search Date Math Issue, unsure of bounds

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm trying to query an amount of records from a database but am a little bit confused about date math. Here's an example of one of my blocks:

```
 var searchParams = {
                    "query": {
                        "bool" : {
                            "must" : [
                                { "term": {  } },
                                { "term": {  } },
                                { "range": {
                                    "dateUTC": {
                                        "gt": "now-7d/d",
                                        "lt": "now/d",
                                    "format": "basic_date_time"
                                    }
                                }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Now if I wanted to query all the result from only today, would I use gt: now-1d/d, lt: now/d. Or would I use gt: now-2d/d, lt: now/d, like the edges around one day? The program I'm trying to make is meant to query all the results from today, yesterday, etc. from the second that the day starts to the Midnight of that day, would I have to switch my date math for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this post answers it pretty clearly: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/several-date-math-questions/27453/3

To answer your questions though:

- "to query all the result from only today": `gt: now/d, lt:now`
- from today midnight to 2 days ago midnight: `gt:now - 2d/d, lt:now/d`

The /d here takes the day calculated in the formula, and adjust time to midnight, so if now is *the 18th of July 00:31:43*, `now/d` yields *the 18th of July 00:00:00*